# I cannot access nor edit an Azure CDN endpoint due to an error "s.@odata.type is not a function"

Tags: azure, cdn

I cannot access nor edit a CDN endpoint due to an error "s.@odata.type is not a function" (see attached screenshot).

[image]

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.